# how to save a hashmap and an image to the same file

Tags: java, image, serialization, hashmap

I wanted to know how to save and load a HashMap(String, List(Object)) to a file.The Object class is shown below:

```
public class FlashCard implements Serializable{
private String question;
private Picture picture;
private ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Picture> pictures = new ArrayList<>();

    public FlashCard(){
    }

    // Method should set a list of answers
    public void setAnswers(ArrayList<String> answers){
        this.answers = answers;
    }

    // Method should add an answer to a list of answers
    public void setAnswer(String answer){
    answers.add(answer);
}

    // Method should set a list of answers
    public void setPictures(ArrayList<Picture> pictures){
        this.pictures = pictures;
    }

     // Method should add an answer to a list of answers
public void setPicture(Picture picture){
    pictures.add(picture);
}


public void setQuestion(String question){
    this.question = question;
}

public ArrayList<String> getAnswers(){
    return answers;
}

public ArrayList<Picture> getPictures(){
    return pictures;
}

public String getQuestion(){
    return question;
}
}
```

The picture class converts from any picture format to a BufferedImage image.I read that the BufferedImage class is not serializable. Does it mean that I cannot save both of them into the same file?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extend `BufferedImage` and have that class implement `Serializable`. Something like this:

```
public class SerializableImage extends BufferedImage implements Serializable{
...
}
```

Then use `SerializableImage` in place of `BufferedImage` and you should be good to go!

Comment: If I put a wrapper around it, like   public class Picture implements Serializable{
 private String filename;
 private BufferedImage image;                                                  Would that method work?

Comment: No because in order for a class to be serializable all of it's class variables must also be serializable.